# parsing simple text with Antlr3.3

Tags: java, parsing, text, antlr

I'm working on a parser in Antlr3.3 that parse a string like 'play bob marley' or 'search bob marley'.
The parser should return which keyword ('play', 'search', ...) I using and return the artist I give. Currently it returns in my Interpreter 'NoViableAltException' where the artist should stand.

Sample.g :

```
grammar Sample;

@header {
    package a.b.c;
    import java.util.HashMap;
}

@lexer::header {
    package a.b.c;
} 


@members {
}

text returns [String s] :
 wordExp SPACE name
;

wordExp  :
  'play' | 'search' 
;

fragment name  : 
    ( TEXT | DIGIT)* 
;


fragment TEXT : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

At the moment it shows that (input: 'play weezer'):

[image]

I try to have an output like this:

[image]

It has been a while I worked with it and I know there have to be a little loop inside but I have no idea right now.

Do you have any idea how that could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parser rules cannot be fragments: remove `fragment` from your `name` rule.

Seems to me you're trying to do something like this:

```
text
 : wordExp name
 ;

name
 : WORD WORD? // one ore two words
 ;

wordExp
 : PLAY
 | SEARCH
 ;

// Keywords definition _before_ the `WORD` rule!
PLAY   : 'play';
SEARCH : 'search';

WORD : ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' )+; // digits in here?

SPACES : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' )+ {skip();};
```

Be aware that parsing such short sentences would be fine, but parsing stuff that resembles English more closely will be difficult to do in ANTLR (or any parser generator using some (E)BNF notation). In that case, google for NLTK.

Comment: Thank you! But it requires the spaces. If I use WORD (' ' WORD)*  it works for me good :)